Gaussian curvature of a general two-dimensional metric
I'm a physics student. I know very little about differential geometry but my thesis topic led me to determine the geodesic curvature of a circle of radius $r = r_{0}$ in a two-dimensional metric of the form:
$$ dd s^{2} = g_{11} (r, \theta) d r^{2} + g_{22} (r, \theta) d \theta^{2} $$
For this purpose I considered a curve $\gamma$ on a surface $S$ described by said metric. The curve $\gamma$ has an arc length parameter $\lambda$ such that its geodesic curvature is
$$ \kappa = \frac{d \mathbf{T}}{d \lambda} \cdot \mathbf{n} $$
where $\mathbf{T} = d \mathbf{r} (\lambda) / d \lambda$ is the unit tangent vector to $\lambda$ and $\mathbf{n}$ the unit normal vector to $\lambda$. For $r = r_{0}$
$$T^{i} = \delta^{i}_{\theta} \frac{d \theta}{d \lambda} = \delta^{i}_{\theta} \frac{1}{\sqrt{g_{22} (r, \theta)}}$$
and the unit normal vector to the curve can be $n_{i} = \delta^{r}_{i} \sqrt{g_{11} (r,\theta)} $. Then,
$$ \kappa = n_{i} \frac{d T^{i}}{d s} |_{r = r_{0}} = n_{i} T^{j} \nabla_{j} T^{i} |_{r = r_{0}} = n_{i} T^{j} \left( \partial_{j} T^{i} + \Gamma^{i} {}_{jl} T^{l} \right)  |_{r = r_{0}} $$
However, from the calculation of the symbols $\Gamma^{i} {}_{j l}$ it is more complicated for me and I did not find any reference for this type of metric. I know that when $g_{11} (r, \theta) \to g_{11} (r) $ and $g_{22} (r, \theta) \to g_{22} (r) $, the geodesic curvature is
$$ \kappa = - \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{g_{11} (r)}} \partial_{r} \ln (g_{22} (r)) |_{r = r_{0}} $$
Could someone give me some reference for calculating the geodesic curvature of this type of two-dimensional metric or guide me?

This problem is perfect for differential forms and the method of moving frames. You can find enough to figure this out in Section 3 of Chapter 3 of my differential geometry text, freely linked in my profile. In Section 3 of Chapter 2 you can also see the straightforward calculation of Christoffel symbols, etc., for such a metric. Note that this is far from a general metric, as $g_{12}=0$ and that simplifies matters considerably.

@TedShifrin Many thanks for the reference and excellent book!. I will add an answer if I manage to solve the problem.
